# Navigate to <a> when <p> is clicked inside <li>

Tags: jquery

I have a few `<li>` elements with the same content structure, I want whenever `p.plink` is clicked to trigger the click of the `<a>` inside that `<li>` element, but can't do it. I want to navigate to the url, just as if I had clicked the actual link.

This is what i tried:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p class="plink" style="background:red;">click me</p>
        <a href="#0">link</a>
        <p>lorem ipsum bl bla</p>
    <li>

    <li>
        <p class="plink" style="background:red;">click me</p>
        <a href="#1">link</a>
        <p>lorem ipsum bl bla</p>
    <li>

    <li>
        <p class="plink" style="background:red;">click me</p>
        <a href="#2">link</a>
        <p>lorem ipsum bl bla</p>
    <li>
</ul>

$('li p.plink').click(function() {
    $(this).next('a').click();
});
```

Comment: .siblings instead of next

Comment: What do you mean by trigger click on anchor? Have you any jquery click handler bound to anchor tags? Or you are looking for simulate user click on anchor?

Comment: Simulate user click. It should follow the link, just like if you clicked the link itself.

Comment: So what you want to do is actually navigate to the `href` URL within the tag. This is different from triggering a click event. You'll want to update your question with that info.

Comment: Did it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call native anchor click method, e.g:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('a').get(0).click();
```

Comment: Nice one master! Once again a perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$('li p.plink').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: This works if I add an event to 'a', but it does not simulate the click (it does not go to the appropriate url). Why?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get the value of "href" and then redirect like this

```
$('li p.plink').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).next('a').attr('href');
    window.location = href;
});
```

Comment: The question was requesting a click trigger. Not a redirect.

Comment: @Lix a click trigger meaning clicking on the link and redirecting, let's wait for the OP to reply before downvoting

Comment: That is an assumption. Not all anchor tags will perform a redirect. Try not to assume what the OP wants and instead read exactly what the requirements are.

Comment: You could have written on the top of your answer - "I assume that you want to navigate to the href within the anchor tag..."

Comment: There is nothing to wait for. The question states exactly what needs to be done. `"trigger the click"`. There is no other way to interpret that statement.

Comment: @Lix Wow you sure want that answer of yours to be selected, calm down buddy. You were also just assuming.

Comment: @Lix It could be trigger the native method click on anchor, but in this case, this answer shouldn't work anyway for internal links as suggested by posted code in question

Comment: Considering that the OP didn't even close his <li> tags correctly, it's a pretty good assumption to say that he wants to redirect

Comment: @user3362707 - I am voting according to the content that is contributed. The fact that I also have an answer on this post is irrelevant. I am very calm. All I'm trying to do is explain to you (as a new user), how things work on [so]. It is a mistake to make assumptions with regard to what the OP is asking, however, if you **are** making assumptions, be safe and state as much in your answer.

Comment: @user3362707 - instead of getting all defensive and accusing me of rep-whoring, take a moment to consider the constructive criticism that a more experienced user is offering. There was nothing forcing me to explain my vote - I chose to do so in order to help you in your future [so] endeavors.

Comment: @Lix I'm not the one getting defensive, you posted 5 comments in a row and downvoted me because my answer is threatening your rep gains, instead of waiting for a clarification

Comment: By downvoting you I actually had reputation taken away from me - so there goes that accusation... I have made no assumptions as to the request of the OP. Therefore I don't need to wait for any clarifications - your assumptions **do require** the OP to clarify their request.

Comment: @user3362707 - now that we have the needed clarification, we can clean up these comments. In the end, your assumptions were correct - but still, untill the OP replied, they were still assumptions.